# Detected borken kqueue while running the Java code in Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, selenium

I am getting the following problems with Selenium Test Run. I am using the tests to create and run on macSierra (10.12) Processor 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7.

I have installed Eclipse, Selenium and Java files from Selenium site.

Here is my code :

```
    package com.some.seleniumproject;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;

public class sampleTest1 {
public static void main (String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "//Library/Java/geckodriver");
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    String baseUrl = "http://www.seleniumhq.org";
    String et = "Selenium - Web Browser Automation";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    String rt = driver.getTitle();
    if (rt.contentEquals(et)) {
        System.out.println("Title is matched");
    }
        else {
            System.out.println("Title is not matched");
        }
    driver.close();
    }

}
```

Here are the errors :

## 1 :

```
    1477536446864   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:11419
Oct 26, 2016 7:47:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
1477536448247   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path /var/folders/dk/xyw6v2zd1bd5sp8pd_4f8fpw0000gn/T/rust_mozprofile.jDvUQye5JfoO
1477536448249   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
1477536448307   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:56571
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
1477536450843   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 56571
1477536453622   Marionette  INFO    startBrowser dab7ebb7-1664-6943-9cc4-e3817dd3a894
Oct 26, 2016 7:47:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0

However, the above error maybe, correct result is thrown in the output.
```

## 2 :

Note: This element has neither has attached source nor attached Java doc and hence no Java
   doc could be found. - this is for the step driver.close();

```
Please help.
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found this bug reported in Mozilla - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1304266. Read a comment to it. 
It looks like libevent issue can cause the problem you've described.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like they had resolved the issue and merged it on Oct, 17.